# Cannot install timeit with pip. How can I fix this?

Tags: python, pip, timeit

I'm trying to install timeit but this is what I get:

```
$ sudo pip install timeit

Downloading/unpacking timeit
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement timeit
No distributions at all found for timeit
Storing complete log in /Users/username/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: `timeit` is included in Python since 2.3. You shouldn't need to install it

Answer (score 10):

`timeit` is part of the Python standard library since 2.3. There should be no need to install it via pip.

Answer (score 4):

That's because timeit is a built in Python module. You don't need to use pip for that.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html

Here's a list of modules included with Python. As long as you have Python installed, you should have these: https://docs.python.org/2/library/

Answer (score 3):

You **don't need to install** it separately. **timeit** is available in python itself. It is available in both 2nd and 3rd versions of python. you can find **timeit** documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html)